# How to create drop down lists from an array, that excludes a certain option - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok so I have this table which lists all employees and their supervisors in a dropdown. 
(the first two options in the drop down are always there the other are there depending weather or not they have been selected as a supervisor in the Supervisor Column)

[image: EmployeeTable]

Now the issue I'm having is someone can't be selected as his/her own supervisor

on the HTML the table rows are simply created using

```
ng-repeat="employeeInfo in employees"
```

and the Drop down select options are loaded like this

```
ng-options="supervisor.id as (supervisor.name + ' ' + supervisor.lastname + ' ' + supervisor.id) for supervisor in supervisorList"
```

how do I exclude the person himself in the drop down of available supervisors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: **EDIT 3 is the working solution**

---

you should add an `ng-if` like this

```
ng-repeat="employeeInfo in employees" ng-if="employeeInfo.id!=currentEmployee.id"
```

(I suppose you have an angular variable `currentEmployee` that you can use for such a check)

**EDIT**

try to add this `ng-if` after the `ng-options` of the drop down select

```
ng-options="supervisor.id as (supervisor.name + ' ' + supervisor.lastname + ' ' + supervisor.id) for supervisor in supervisorList" ng-if="employeeInfo.id!=supervisor.id"
```

**EDIT 2**

before executing the `ng-options` that generates the drop down, execute this piece of code

```
supervisorListCopy = $filter('filter')(supervisorList, function(value, index) {return value.id !== employeeInfo.id;})
```

then you can generate the drop down using the filtered list

```
ng-options="supervisor.id as (supervisor.name + ' ' + supervisor.lastname + ' ' + supervisor.id) for supervisor in supervisorListCopy"
```

**EDIT 3**

the simplest way to do it is to apply filter aside the `ng-options` like below

```
ng-options="supervisor.id as (supervisor.name + ' ' + supervisor.lastname + ' ' + supervisor.id) for supervisor in supervisorListCopy | filter: '!' + employeeInfo.id"
```

Comment: the ng-repeat is to populate the entire table, I'm looking to remove the option on the drop down, if it is the same as university number on the table row

Comment: well, can you share more source code then? so I can refine my answer :)

Comment: @LegionDev, I added a new solution

Comment: I tried this but if the if Statement is true it removes the entire drop down,and not just that option

Comment: @LegionDev, added new solution (EDIT 2), please try it :)

Comment: I found the solution thanks to you :) I simply needed to add "| filter: '!' + employeeInfo.id" at the end of ng-options

Comment: @LegionDev, yes! ahahah I forgot the simplest way to do it :) I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Best and clean method would be using filters. i.e EDIT 3.